# Authenticate Cognito IDP API in Amplify js application

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-sdk-js, amplifyjs

I'm trying to use `CognitoIdentityProviderClient` server side in my next.js application that also uses amplify js library and amplify hosting. It works perfectly locally, but the client is not authenticated and authorized after deploy.

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth/next';
import errorString from '@/utils/errorString';
import { authOptions } from '@/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth]';
// import { defaultProvider } from '@aws-sdk/credential-provider-node';

import {
  AdminGetUserCommand,
  CognitoIdentityProviderClient,
} from '@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider';

import { updatedAwsConfig } from '@/utils/amplify-init';

const handler = async (
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) => {
    try {
        const session = await getServerSession(req, res, authOptions)
        const { user } = session || {};

        const region = updatedAwsConfig.aws_cognito_region;

        const adminGetUser = async ({ userPoolId, username }) => {
            const client = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient({ region,
                     // credentials: defaultProvider()
                  });
            
            const command = new AdminGetUserCommand({
                UserPoolId: userPoolId,
                Username: username,
            });
            
            return client.send(command);
        };

        const userPoolId = updatedAwsConfig.aws_user_pools_id;
        const username = user.username;

        const data = await adminGetUser({userPoolId, username});

        return res.status(200).json({ data });
    } catch(error) {
        return res.status(500).json({ error: errorString(error) });
    }
    
};

export default handler;
```

It probably uses some credentials like ~/.aws/credentials locally and doesn't have them server side. I also tried  defaultProvider from @aws-sdk/credential-provider-node without success. I also assigned the same IAM roles for the backend role as I have for my local amplify without success.
Are there ideas how could I make CognitoIdentityProviderClient work properly?

I need server side credentials for the admin api. Users don't have amplify sessions.